# Error when dismissing a MPmovieViewController in landscape to a view in portrait only (UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm creating an xcode application for IOS7 that work in portrait mod in most views.

The project setting allows "Portrait" "Landscape Left" and "Landscape Right".

In views that I only want to appears in portrait i add the following code to lock them in portrait mode :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

In one of these locked views i present a MPmovieViewController using the following code :

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *movieViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:replayURL];
    movieViewController.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movieViewController];
```

This code create a MPmovieViewController that i can use in Portrait and Landscape. (that's what i want)

The problem appears when i press the done button of the MPMovieViewController to dismiss the MovieController when in landscape mode. The previous view doesn't support the landscape mode so i have the following error :

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation must return a supported interface orientation!'
```

How can i force the rotation back to portrait mode when dismiss MPMovieViewController?

Best regards

Richard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering myself. In fact it was very simple.

Just add to the portrait only view :

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation { return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait; }
```

Thanks